# PHP if statement not functioning correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run an if statment then checks if a cell in database holds a certain value then it sets a variable, if it does not contain that value then it sets a different value

I have tried the following code

```
        case "Chemistry":
        $type_tarin_text = ' Exp in ';
        if($user_playerdata_tab['profile_type']='Drug Runner') {
        $treining_value =$sp_value*11;
        } else {
        $treining_value =$sp_value*10;
        }
        $this->AddSubValueByUserID($player_id,'PlayerData','CHEMISTRY_EXP',$treining_value);
        break;
```

It is currently setting the $treining_value as $sp_value*11 regardless of wether profile_type is 'Drug Runner' or not.

Comment: `= !== == && = !== ===` - <insert-3-equals-dupe-here>.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `==` or strict `===` since you're expecting a string.

You're now assigning a variable which is likely not what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As others have helpfully pointed out, the issue is here:

```
$user_playerdata_tab['profile_type']='Drug Runner'
```

The single `=` means assignment. What you were intending to do was to test whether the two were equal.

That means using `==` - or, to be more strict, use `===` (make that your go-to equality check in the future - you'll thank us later)

Your other assignments are fine, though I would recommend a single space both sides of your `=` signs for readability

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this seems to have fliped the issue round. It is now setting $treining_value as the 2nd one regardless or wether what is in profile_type cell

Comment: It clearly doesn't like the if statement, I tried testign it with other things that are definitely true. I thin tried taking out the else and it gave me the value of 0

Comment: Sorted, it, stupid mistake, wasn't passing the necessary information into the function.